# Importing file from same directory working in one python file but not another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have these two python files.

[image]

api.py has a class called API, which is imported by `__init__.py` using `from api import API`. Before this file was named `__init__.py`, this worked perfectly. But when I changed the name to `__init__.py` so that I could use it with Flask, I now get the error `Unable to import 'api'` under the `from` keyword. Doing `from directoryName.api import API` works, but the directory name is different on my computer and on my VPS. I could just change the name of the directory to make them the same, but I'd prefer if there was a way that I could change the directory name at any point and it wouldn't break the script.

Does anyone know, firstly, why this doesn't work in `__init__.py`? And secondly, a way to import a file from the same directory in the init file?

Thanks!

Comment: one way to import from `api` would be `from .api import API` (see leading . before api).

Comment: Did you try from .api import API

Comment: @oli @Manish Gupta I've tried that but then I get this error: `Unable to import '__init__.api'` and, for reference, the directory name is not `__init__`

Comment: May I know where and how you're importing this module?

Comment: Can you try after deleting __pycache__ directory

Comment: Deleting pycache didn't do much, but actually the error above is just a linter error and is different from the actual error. I tried `from .api import API` on my VPS and it actually works, but on my pc, I get the error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. I'm just running it from the command line with `python __init__.py` while my VPS is running it through WSGI